# Calculate Stock From Two Sold Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, join

I have three tables `STOCK`, `SOLD` and `SOLD1` in MS Access and SQL Server. My question is how to calculate total stock SKU wise ie. (stock - the sum of stock from sold and sold2 tables)

[image: Access Table Diagram]

I have tried with left joins on both sold tables with `STOCK` table but I am getting incorrect results, sold table stock is calculated twice or thrice.

For that matter, I tried to calculate sold stock separately and I get SOLD2 total wrong.

My query is

```
SELECT 
    STOCK.ID, STOCK.SKU, STOCK.QTY, 
    SUM(SOLD.QTY) AS SS1, SUM(SOLD2.QTY) AS SS2 
FROM 
    (STOCK 
LEFT JOIN 
    SOLD ON STOCK.SKU = SOLD.SKU) 
LEFT JOIN 
    WSITEMS AS SOLD2 ON STOCK.SKU = SOLD2.SKU 
GROUP BY 
    STOCK.ID, STOCK.SKU, STOCK.QTY;
```

[image: QUERY RESULT]

(In SOLD2 TOTAL OF SKU 1003 IS 20 BUT it is showing 40 and TOTAL OF SKU 1005 IS 30 but it is showing 120)

Could you please tell me how to get correct sold quantity after calculating from both the sold tables.

I have tried in access first but I want it for SQL Server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate *before* joining.  However, I would recommend two separate joins:

```
SELECT S.ID, S.SKU, S.QTY, 
       NZ(SO.TOTAL, 0) + NZ(S2.TOTAL) as SOLD_QTY
FROM (STOCK AS S LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT SKU, SUM(QTY) AS TOTAL 
       FROM SOLD AS SO
       GROUP BY SO.SKU
      ) AS SO
      ON SO.SKU = S.SKU
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SKU,  SUM(QTY) AS TOTAL  
      FROM WSITEMS S2 
      GROUP BY S2.SKU
     ) AS S2
     ON S.SKU = S2.SKU;
```

This lets you list the two sold quantities from each table as separate columns, if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
     SELECT STOCK.ID,STOCK.SKU,STOCK.QTY, 
      SOLDA.TOTAL AS SOLD_QTY FROM STOCK LEFT 
       JOIN
       (SELECT SKU,  Sum(QTY) AS TOTAL from SOLD 
        group by SOLD.SKU
        Union all
         SELECT SKU,  Sum(QTY) AS TOTAL  from SOLD2 
         group by SKU) AS SOLDA
         ON STOCK.SKU=SOLDA.SKU
```

Comment: Thanks, Deepak you have really saved my time. IF you could help me with one more query, I have tried to calculate available stock by subtracting STOCK.QTY FORM the query and I am getting the correct answer but only for those articles which are in sold tables, however, I was wondering how to get qty as a whole for those articles which are not in sold tabes

Comment: my new query is as SELECT STOCK.ID,STOCK.SKU,STOCK.QTY, 
      STOCK.QTY - SOLDA.TOTAL AS SQTY FROM STOCK LEFT 
       JOIN
       (SELECT SKU,  Sum(QTY) AS TOTAL from SOLD 
        group by SOLD.SKU
        Union all
         SELECT SKU,  Sum(QTY) AS TOTAL  from WSITEMS 
         group by SKU) AS SOLDA
         ON STOCK.SKU=SOLDA.SKU

Comment: sorry sold2 is as WSITEMS IN MY access table

Comment: Since we have done left join you should get all records from STOCK table. But if you have records in SOLD table but not in STOCK then those will be missed. I guess null values are creating issue. You can use coalesce

Comment: Use this coalesce(STOCK.QTY,0) - coalesce(SOLDA.TOTAL,0) AS SQTY. Also can you accept the answer